# Qt connect of a ui member and two signals in the same connection

Tags: c++, qt, signals

I would like to understand a simple piece of code I came across. It is a connection between an object of the interface and two signals.

The code is:

```
 connect( ui->checkbox_legEnabled,
    SIGNAL( stateChanged( int ) ), SIGNAL( edited() ) );
```

What is the meaning of this line of code?

Thanks,
Sara

Answer (score 2):

With Qt signals and slots, you can directly connect one signal to another signal (or non-`signal` member function), without having a slot in between. See connection function invoked here is [this overload](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#connect-2) of `QObject::connect`.

This line of code hence means, whenever the object `ui->checkbox_legEnabled` (presumably some kind of `QCheckbox`) emits the `stateChanged` signal (that has an `int` parameter passed along), directly emit another signal (or ordinary member function) `edited` (without parameters).

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is you can connect a signal to another signal and that means that the second signal will also emit whenever the first signal is emitted, read more about signals and slots in the documentation [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html), also check out the new way to call connect (with function pointers)

Now in your case what it does it's basically allows you to keep the `ui` private, but in the same time forward the signals you want to the outside of your object, by allowing other objects to connect to the signal(s) you provide in the interface.

Incomplete usage example (based on your code, i named the class that contains your code `MyWidget`): the main-window (or whoever) that has access to your widget can be notified whenever something changes inside, by connecting to the `edited` signal:

```
void MainWindow::createMyWidget()
{
    m_myWidget = new MyWidget(this);
    connect(m_myWidget, &MyWidget::edited, this, &MainWindow::myWidgetWasEdited));
}
```

This way whenever something changes inside `MyWidget` the `MainWindow` can be notified about the edit and it can take the necessary actions inside the `myWidgetWasEdited` slot.

This can be expanded, if needed, to provide an signal for each particular "edit" instead of a single generic `edited` signal (but this depends on your needs).